# How to get current MDX in Tableau?

Tags: mdx, tableau-api

Given a PivotTable in Tableau, is there a way to know the associated MDX Query?

I would help my understanding current pivot table and fix potential misconstructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike ProClarity and some other MDX-generating tools, you can't see the MDX being created while in the UI. However, if you open up the \My Documents\My Tableau Repository\Logs folder, you'll see Desktop's logs. You can open those up and see each and every MDX statement that has been executed against SSAS.

Hope this helps!