# Tableau desktop doesn't generate logs

Tags: logging, mdx, tableau-api

I wsa following this note to try to view the MDX queries behind Tableau ([How to get current MDX in Tableau?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686809/how-to-get-current-mdx-in-tableau/35013232?noredirect=1#comment57753250_35013232)) but, I have realized it doesn't generate logs since some months ago.
Any ideas what it could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ["performance recorder"](http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.html#perf_record_create_desktop.html) which will show the queries that Tableau Desktop is creating and how long they take to run. See more here: http://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/online/en-us/help.html#perf_record_interpret_desktop.html

Also, you can get the full desktop logs by following these steps: http://kb.tableau.com/articles/knowledgebase/sending-tableau-desktop-log-files

Comment: Thanks, but now I have two problems. When I try to start Performance Recorder it says: The system cannot find the path specified. And the logs are not generated yet!

Comment: If that doesn't work I'd consider raising a support ticket.

Comment: the second approach doesn't work on some user unfortunately.

Comment: I believe you may need Admin rights on your machine in order to run the performance recorder.